# Can't Access Declared Structure with an Object

Tags: c#, oop, structure

I am using a Structure shown below

```
public struct TPCANMsg
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 11/29-bit message identifier
    /// </summary>
    public uint ID;
    /// <summary>
    /// Type of the message
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public TPCANMessageType MSGTYPE;  
    /// <summary>
    /// Data Length Code of the message (0..8)
    /// </summary>
    public byte LEN;      
    /// <summary>
    /// Data of the message (DATA[0]..DATA[7])
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public byte[] DATA;   
}
```

Then declared the object for structure in below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Peak.Can.Basic;

namespace rcToOnBoardPC
{
    class Communication
    {
       // CAN Status Decalaration
       TPCANStatus gStatus;
       // List of CAN Messages
       TPCANMsg msg1 = new TPCANMsg();    
       msg1.ID = 0x100; 

    }
}
```

I get following Error"Error 1   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration." 
Can not understand that why can not I access the structure with the respective object. Please guide.

Comment: `msg1.ID = 0x100;` is floating outside a method, put it in the ctor?

Comment: Or just `TPCANMsg msg1 = new TPCANMsg{ID = 0x100};`

Comment: @AlexK. Please elaborate "ctor". Please try to put it in simpler words. I am not as well equipped like you when it comes to programming. An example is preferred. As while asking questions one must be clear I would expect that experts when giving answer are clearer.

Comment: `ctor` is a widely used term for *constructor* as in `public Communication() { msg1.ID = 0x100; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question involves a simple typographical error, it probably should be closed as such, and may well be eventually.

In the meantime, here is what the commenters are trying to tell you…

The basic problem is that you have written a program statement outside of a method. In C# (and indeed, any similar language) this is not allowed. Program statements are required to be contained within a method (aka "function").

You can resolve the problem in one of two ways. The easiest to understand is to put the statement in a method (i.e. comply directly with the language rule you're running up against):

```
class Communication
{
   // CAN Status Decalaration
   TPCANStatus gStatus;
   // List of CAN Messages
   TPCANMsg msg1 = new TPCANMsg();

   public Communication()
   {
       msg1.ID = 0x100; 
   }
}
```

The second way to address the issue relies on the fact that while program *statements* can't exist outside of a method, you can use *expressions* in a variety of contexts, including initializers. And C# has an initializer syntax that allows you to include assignment statements as part of the initialization. I.e. technically you are simply writing an initialization expression, but in that context you're allowed to write a little block of code that, as long as the only type of program statement it includes is an assignment, is legal even though it's outside of a method

That approach would look like this:

```
class Communication
{
   // CAN Status Decalaration
   TPCANStatus gStatus;
   // List of CAN Messages
   TPCANMsg msg1 = new TPCANMsg { ID = 0x100 };
}
```

Note that when using that syntax, you are also allowed to omit the parens `()` from the invocation of the parameterless constructor. This is not required; if you prefer writing `new TPCANMsg() { ID = 0x100 }`, that's allowed too.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I figured it out but still its a very good answer and appreciated for taking some time out to help people like us. I hope more people have the patience you show. Cant thank you enough....